# Unable to pull data from rxjs observable

Tags: angular, typescript, service, rxjs, observable

I have a service that provides an observable collection of 'Recipe'

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecipeService {

  recipes: Recipe[];
  private _recipesSource = new Subject<Recipe[]>();
  recipesMessage$ = this._recipesSource.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.recipes = new Array<Recipe>();
    this.recipes.push(new Recipe('Recipe1', 1));
    this.recipes.push(new Recipe('Recipe2', 2));
    this.recipes.push(new Recipe('Recipe3', 3));
    this._recipesSource.next(this.recipes);
  }
}
```

Additionally, I have an angular component that creates a vertical list of buttons for each recipe from `RecipeService`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-list',
  template: `
    <div class="btn-group-vertical">
      <button
        *ngFor="let recipe of rs.recipesMessage$ | async"
        type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
        a
      </button>
   </div>
  `
})
export class RecipeListComponent implements OnInit {

  recipes: Recipe[];
  constructor(private rs: RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.recipes = new Array();
  } 
}
```

The issue that I'm having is that the buttons are not appearing when the page is served. It appears that my subscription is returning nothing.

ps. Forgive me if my TypeScript isn't great. I'm new to the Javascript universe, and feedback is always welcome.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz ? I guess you're code is absolutely fine and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't work because you use `Subject` and pass values to it in `constructor`.

Because `Subject` is a *hot* Observable by itself, when you push value to it, it emits them immediately, so in your case, when Angular runs `constructor` function for your `RecipeService`. But at that time, template of `RecipeListComponent` is not yet ready, so `| async` has not fired yet.

Usually, in these scenarios, **BehaviorSubject** is used. It preserves the last emitted value to late subscribers:

```
private _recipesSource = new BehaviorSubject<Recipe[]>([]);
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks!  Just curious - is there a preferred pattern or lifecycle hook that I should use alternatively?

Comment: I use this, other devs I see uses also. So i consider this as a preferred pattern. No need to worry about the timings here. There are no hooks in services in Angular

Answer (score 1):

This is because `recipes` change is not catched by Angular change detection as it is mutated in an aync subscrition call.

Replace

`*ngFor="let recipe of recipes"`

with

`*ngFor="let recipe of rs.recipesMessage$ | async"`

And  you can remove

```
loadRecipes(): void {
    this.rs.recipesMessage$
      .subscribe(
        recipes => this.recipes = recipes
      );
  }
```

as well as

`this.loadRecipes()` in `ngOnInit`

Comment: Definitely some high-quality advice here, but it's still not working (code in question is updated). I'm going to post a more complete stackblitz.

Comment: Sure, will modify my answer to a stackblitz link based on your complete stackblitz.

Comment: Or try to make rs injection public in ```RecipeListComponent``` constructor: ```public rs: RecipeService```